# How is minimumPlatformVersion specified by a Corda Node on the Network Map?

Tags: corda

Is the `minimumPlatformVersion` parameter on the node manually populated in a config file (e.g the node.conf) used in the network map?

Or is this field automatically populated on the network map given the version of Corda that is running on the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the node version in the node.conf, it's sent automatically to the network map by the Corda version you're running.